# Clang showing compiler error with fuzzer argument

Tags: clang, llvm, fuzzing

I am trying to experiment with libFuzzer library and going through the toy-example[1].

```
keep-learnings-MacBook-Pro:Ccodeanalysis keep_learning$ cat Fuzzme.cpp 
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t *data, size_t size) {
  if (size > 0 && data[0] == 'H')
    if (size > 1 && data[1] == 'I')
       if (size > 2 && data[2] == '!')
       __builtin_trap();
  return 0;
}

keep-learnings-MacBook-Pro:Ccodeanalysis keep_learning$ clang++ -fsanitize=address,fuzzer Fuzzme.cpp 
ld: file not found: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.fuzzer_osx.a
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

keep-learnings-MacBook-Pro:Ccodeanalysis keep_learning$ clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

A quick Google search showed me this [2], but other than that I could not find any meaningful information to resolve it, hence posting here.  Could some one please tell me how to solve this ? Thanks in advance.

[1] http://llvm.org/docs/LibFuzzer.html#toy-example 
[2] https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39794

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have noticed, there is no fuzzer runtime shipped with Apple developer tools. So you'd either report this issue to Apple folks, or build the runtime library by yourself from the sources (or both).

Comment: Thanks for the answer@Anton. I would report a issue with Apple.

Answer (score 1):

As Anton stated, Apple Developer Tools do not include the fuzzer library, leaving you to compile from source, or asking Apple.

It turns out [LLVM](https://llvm.org) also hosts pre-compiled binaries for some releases on [their downloads page](https://releases.llvm.org/download.html):

https://releases.llvm.org/download.html.

On that page, find your LLVM version (eg ["Download LLVM 10.0.0"](https://releases.llvm.org/download.html#10.0.0)), and go a bit further until you see **Pre-Built Binaries**.  Don't see binaries for your LLVM version? Pick the nearest *lower* version. The OP and I both have clang++ 10.0.1, so we'd pick [10.0.0](https://releases.llvm.org/download.html#10.0.0).

Click the *macOS* link to download, pop into the Terminal to untar and copy the libraries, and you're done.  I did it with a few environment variables (those paths are killer!), and a `cp -n` to preserve existing files.

```
export CLANG_ROOT=clang+llvm-10.0.0-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/clang/10.0.0
export XCODE_ROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1

tar xvf clang+llvm-10.0.0-x86_64-apple-darwin.tar.xz  $CLANG_ROOT/include/fuzzer $CLANG_ROOT/lib/darwin

sudo cp -rn $CLANG_ROOT/include/fuzzer $XCODE_ROOT/include
sudo cp -n $CLANG_ROOT/lib/darwin/* $XCODE_ROOT/lib/darwin
```

I did exactly the above, and my code compiled and linked right away.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30144141)