# Clang libFizzer for AArch64 architecture

Tags: c++, xcode, llvm, clang++, fuzzing

I would like to perform some fuzz testing on a command-line application I am working on. I am on an M1 Mac, and apple developer tools does not ship clang with libFuzzer. So I followed [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57735108/clang-showing-compiler-error-with-fuzzer-argument)'s answer and ended up linking the prebuilt binary for libFuzzer with Apple's distro on my device. I know it was linked correctly because now it acknowledges the command line argument `fuzzer`, but complains about the architecture. When executing `clang++ fuzz-test85.cpp -std=c++14 -g -fsanitize=fuzzer`:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/13.1.6/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.fuzzer_osx.a, file is universal (x86_64,x86_64h) but does not contain the arm64 architecture: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/13.1.6/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.fuzzer_osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But I cannot find an AArch64 binary or source code for MacOS anywhere. Is there a workaround to this? Invoking with `--verbose` results in:

```
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.3)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple arm64-apple-macosx12.0.0 -Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_ -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -emit-obj -mrelax-all --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name fuzz-test85.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=non-leaf -fno-strict-return -fno-rounding-math -munwind-tables -target-sdk-version=12.3 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden-static-local-var -target-cpu apple-m1 -target-feature +v8.5a -target-feature +fp-armv8 -target-feature +neon -target-feature +crc -target-feature +crypto -target-feature +dotprod -target-feature +fp16fml -target-feature +ras -target-feature +lse -target-feature +rdm -target-feature +rcpc -target-feature +zcm -target-feature +zcz -target-feature +fullfp16 -target-feature +sm4 -target-feature +sha3 -target-feature +sha2 -target-feature +aes -target-abi darwinpcs -fallow-half-arguments-and-returns -debug-info-kind=standalone -dwarf-version=4 -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 762 -v -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/13.1.6 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include -stdlib=libc++ -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/13.1.6/include -internal-externc-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -internal-externc-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -Wno-reorder-init-list -Wno-implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-c99-designator -Wno-final-dtor-non-final-class -Wno-extra-semi-stmt -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-enum-float-conversion -Wno-elaborated-enum-base -Wno-reserved-identifier -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -Wno-objc-load-method -std=c++14 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=/Users/liamwhite/documents/projects/cpp/weekly -ferror-limit 19 -fsanitize-coverage-type=3 -fsanitize-coverage-indirect-calls -fsanitize-coverage-trace-cmp -fsanitize-coverage-inline-8bit-counters -fsanitize-coverage-pc-table -fsanitize=address,fuzzer,fuzzer-no-link -fsanitize-system-ignorelist=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/13.1.6/share/asan_ignorelist.txt -fsanitize-address-use-after-scope -fsanitize-address-globals-dead-stripping -fno-assume-sane-operator-new -fno-builtin-bcmp -fno-builtin-memcmp -fno-builtin-strncmp -fno-builtin-strcmp -fno-builtin-strncasecmp -fno-builtin-strcasecmp -fno-builtin-strstr -fno-builtin-strcasestr -fno-builtin-memmem -stack-protector 1 -mdarwin-stkchk-strong-link -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fno-cxx-modules -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fcommon -fcolor-diagnostics -clang-vendor-feature=+messageToSelfInClassMethodIdReturnType -clang-vendor-feature=+disableInferNewAvailabilityFromInit -clang-vendor-feature=+disableNonDependentMemberExprInCurrentInstantiation -fno-odr-hash-protocols -clang-vendor-feature=+enableAggressiveVLAFolding -clang-vendor-feature=+revert09abecef7bbf -clang-vendor-feature=+thisNoAlignAttr -clang-vendor-feature=+thisNoNullAttr -mllvm -disable-aligned-alloc-awareness=1 -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o /var/folders/8q/3gr0csbs7wvflhl0v43wpgqh0000gn/T/fuzz-test85-e73eea.o -x c++ ./fuzz-test85.cpp
clang -cc1 version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.3) default target arm64-apple-darwin21.3.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/13.1.6/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -no_deduplicate -dynamic -arch arm64 -platform_version macos 12.0.0 12.3 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -o a.out -L/usr/local/lib /var/folders/8q/3gr0csbs7wvflhl0v43wpgqh0000gn/T/fuzz-test85-e73eea.o -lc++ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/13.1.6/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib -rpath @executable_path -rpath /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/13.1.6/lib/darwin /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/13.1.6/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.fuzzer_osx.a -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/13.1.6/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/13.1.6/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.fuzzer_osx.a, file is universal (x86_64,x86_64h) but does not contain the arm64 architecture: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/13.1.6/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.fuzzer_osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If there is no workaround to this, can anyone suggest an alternate fuzz tester compatible with the M1 Mac? I've looked into American Fuzzy Lop Fuzzer but I don't see anything for AArch64 architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to Download LLVM source code and build clang and compiler-rt by yourself.

Update 2022/07/20.

Maybe you need to install llvm by yourself. Like this lib does.

Notes on AppleClang
The default AppleClang provided by Xcode does not work as it does not contain [libFuzzer](https://github.com/nlohmann/fuzzcover). In that case, you will get a linker error such as

`ld: file not found: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.5/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.fuzzer_osx.a clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

You need to install Clang via Homebrew, add it to your path, and tell CMake to use it:

`brew install llvm exportPATH=$(brew --prefix llvm)/bin:$PATHCXX=clang cmake ..`

Comment: Maybe you need to install llvm by yourself. Like this lib does.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message ("libclang_rt.fuzzer_osx.a, file is universal (x86_64,x86_64h) but does not contain the arm64 architecture"), my guess is that you accidentally downloaded the pre-built LLVM release for x86_64.

You want something that looks like "clang+llvm-15.0.2-arm64-apple-darwin21.0.tar.xz".

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases